# Zero ClipBoard issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I am trying to integrate Zero Clipboard into tornado web application and I am running into some problems.

http://jonrohan.github.io/ZeroClipboard/#demo this page works perfectly, but when I try to view same page on my local machine ('Save page as..' to get all the files locally) after opening HTML file I get http://snag.gy/sT1y2.jpg . And this happens (same error) even if I do everything what is written in tutorial (only required lines of code).

Maybe some one had similar problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and I made it to work by uploading it to server where it worked fine.
Instead of testing it on local, please test it some where on server.